# Delay ON signal from sensor (NPN)

Tags: opto-isolator, 555, npn, infrared, delay

I have sensor (slotted IR optocoupler) that has IR diode and IR detector (transistor), where emitter is connected to ground. On device side I have connector with 3 pins - Vcc, GND and signal line, where signal line has internal 10K pull-up resistor.

I would like to create circuit between device and sensor board that creates delay after IR detector detects light and signal line goes low. I would like the delay to be around 10ms. That delay should be applied only on transition from sensor being activated (OFF->ON) and not when going to deactivated state. On that transition there shouldn't be any delay. Vcc is 3.3V, so probably IC555 is not feasible in this case.

I tried placing capacitor between signal line and GND but it makes delay after sensor being deactivated, but not when being activated. Unfortunately can't modify sensor board or device itself.

How to achieve the desired delay?

[image: schematic with IR sensor board and device]

Comment: the LED/transistor pair is drawn upside down

Answer (score 0):

With the LED and output emitter connected, your options are limited.

If the device requires a crisp edge rather than a slow ramp for its input signal, you will need a circuit with an active element.  One transistor will get you a reasonable edge, while two transistors will get you a fast edge.

Another option is a Schmitt Trigger gate as the active element.  These are available in SOT packages.  For example, two of these in series:

SN74LVC1G14

I would put the R-C stage between the two inverters.

Is this a one-off project or something for production?

Comment: I have few devices that have some problem with this sensor and timing, but I figured out that if I delay the on signal from sensor it solves the problem, so I will probably draw a pcb, order a few and solder them to solve that problem.